# What is the default timezone for java.util.Calendar.?

Tags: java, date, calendar

**Code**

```
public String testDate(){ 
      TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("US/Eastern"));
      Calendar fromDate = Calendar.getInstance();
      Date date= new Date();
      System.out.println(fromDate);
      System.out.println(date);
}
```

My calendar variable shows a cdate value `2013-12-09T00:00:00.000Z` and  time value `1386649779590` while debugging the calendar variable below.

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
```

Complete Calendar details which i have seen while printing the object

```
System.out.println(cal);
```

**Console**

```
java.util.GregorianCalendar[time=1386649779590,areFieldsSet=true,areAllFieldsSet=true,lenient=true,zone=sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfo[id="US/Eastern",offset=-18000000,dstSavings=3600000,useDaylight=true,transitions=235,lastRule=java.util.SimpleTimeZone[id=US/Eastern,offset=-18000000,dstSavings=3600000,useDaylight=true,startYear=0,startMode=3,startMonth=2,startDay=8,startDayOfWeek=1,startTime=7200000,startTimeMode=0,endMode=3,endMonth=10,endDay=1,endDayOfWeek=1,endTime=7200000,endTimeMode=0]],firstDayOfWeek=1,minimalDaysInFirstWeek=1,ERA=1,YEAR=2013,MONTH=11,WEEK_OF_YEAR=50,WEEK_OF_MONTH=2,DAY_OF_MONTH=9,DAY_OF_YEAR=343,DAY_OF_WEEK=2,DAY_OF_WEEK_IN_MONTH=2,AM_PM=1,HOUR=11,HOUR_OF_DAY=23,MINUTE=29,SECOND=39,MILLISECOND=590,ZONE_OFFSET=-18000000,DST_OFFSET=0]
```

While my java.util.date variable shows a date as `Mon Dec 09 07:37:50 EST 2013`, while debugging the date variable

```
Date date= new Date();
```

where as my default `timezone` that i have set is **EST** specified on program start

```
TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("US/Eastern"));
```

And i am working from a `timezone` **IST**.

My question is

**Why is `cal` of `Calendar` and `date` of `Date()` different ?**

Comment: It's very hard to follow your question. You can easily check the time zone of a calendar by calling `getTimeZone`. If that doesn't give you enough information, please post a short but *complete* program demonstrating the problem. We have no idea what you mean by "My calendar variable shows a time as [...]" when we don't know how you're seeing that value.

Comment: @JonSkeet i have posted the result that i have checked. But i did't get the timezone

Comment: What do you mean "I have posted the result that I have checked"? Where? Your whole question is hard to understand.

Comment: @JonSkeet 2013-12-09T00:00:00.000Z this is the value i found while debuging the Calendar variable

Comment: @JonSkeet i was asking that the getDefault timezone is the default timezone for Date variable right.?? So what is the default timeZone value for Calendar. since both the values are not same, i belive they are taking different values as there timezone.!

Comment: No, you weren't. You were asking what the default time zone was for Calendar, which isn't the same as Date. You never asked about the default time zone for Date, which is only actually relevant in the toString call. (A `Date` instance doesn't have a time zone; `toString` just uses the current default time zone.) And you *still* haven't said exactly what produced the "value you found" - yes, you were debugging, but that doesn't actually tell us much. A short but complete program would have been *much* more informative.

Comment: @JonSkeet sorry if you did't get my point, but i believe i posted every relevant code here . Everything here happens in 2 line so i just posted that code here. Hope i you get what i have asked

Comment: No, you haven't posted "every relevant code". We still don't know how you're seeing 2013-12-09T00:00:00.000Z - it may well be a debugger visualization. A short but complete program would have made this question *much* simpler, as it wouldn't have relied on how you happen to be debugging your code. (We don't even know which IDE you're using.) Please read http://tinyurl.com/so-list and http://tinyurl.com/so-hints

Comment: I'll just toss out there that in no timezone is epoch 1386592669972 equal to `2013-12-09T00:00:00.000Z`. Epoch 1386592669972 is `2013-12-09T12:37:49.972Z`. You need to show exactly how you saw the first date - debugger or `toString()` or what. A [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) would be best.

Comment: @JonSkeet I have made the change as instructed please take a look :)

Comment: You've given various bits of output which I don't think are from the same run. Show the output from *one run* otherwise it's hopeless. I would also *strongly* advise you to ignore whatever bits and bobs you're seeing while debugging - it's not clear what you mean by a "cdate" value for example. It's also unclear what you're confused about now. The console output *shows* that the calendar has a time zone of US Eastern, and the `Date` output is showing EST as well - what's confusing?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

According to [Oracle Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html) it is clearly mentioned that,

> public static Calendar getInstance()
>   Gets a calendar using the default time zone and locale. The Calendar returned is based on the current time in the default time zone with the default locale.

And the `default time zone` is got by `public static TimeZone getDefault()` and it is mentioned in [TimeZone.getDefault()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TimeZone.html#getDefault()) that

> Gets the default TimeZone for this host. The source of the default TimeZone may vary with implementation.

It will return the `default` timezone set in your computer until and unless you have used `public static void setDefault(TimeZone zone)` function to set the `TimeZone` explicitly.

**I believe the above explanation answers your both the question,**

1. What is the default timezone of java.util.Calendar.?
2. Why is my variable cal of type Calendar shows a time that is not IST or EST.?

**EDIT:** As per your edited question

> Why is cal of Calendar and date of Date() different?

When you call `System.out.println(date);` then `toString()` function is invoked and if you look at [Source Code of Date](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/Date.java#Date.toString%28%29) you will find that it returns 3 letters shorthand for timezone by invoking the `displayName` function of default time zone which is 3 letters shorthand in your case `EST`, which is `U.S. Eastern Standard Time (GMT-05:00) Indiana (East)`.

Comment: Okie the first part is solved but why is the two date shown different while debugging.?

Answer (score 4):

The date itself doesn't have any time zone. It's `toString()` method uses the current default time zone to return a String

Answer (score 3):

Typically, you get a `TimeZone` using `getDefault` which creates a `TimeZone` based on the time zone where the program is running. For example, for a program running in Japan, `getDefault` creates a `TimeZone` object based on Japanese Standard Time.

Check [`TimeZone`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TimeZone.html) for more

Comment: yes the Timezones is default value is used by Date but calender and date are different they use different timezone values

Comment: @Dileep: No, they really don't. If you believe they do, you should show that in a short but complete program demonstrating the problem, as I've asked before.

Answer (score 1):

You mention "cdate", and I notice there is a field inside the Calendar object called `cdate`. In running your sample code, I see that the `cdate` field is indeed initialized to `2013-12-10T00:00:00.000Z` (it now being 24 hours later of course).

So? I don't know why you are looking at internal fields of a class when you are never going to directly use them.

Your solution, then, is to ignore it. Don't worry about the `cdate` field of your Calendar; worry about things that actually affect your program.

The `toString()` of a `Calendar` is not very pretty and is intended for debugging; you should call `cal.getTime()` which will give you a `java.util.Date` that you can then print out either directly or by using a `java.text.DateFormatter`.