# Getting the last time for the current day via the Calendar gives a wrong result

Tags: java, date, calendar

I'm trying to get the last time of the current day.
For example:
The last time for today would be 10.07.2015 23:59:59:999

Therefore i have written the following method:

```
private static Date getLastDateOfDay() {
    final Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 999);
    cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 59);
    cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 59);
    cal.set(Calendar.HOUR, 23);
    return cal.getTime();
}
```

This should get the current date and then set:

hours to 23

minutes to 59

seconds to 59

miliseconds to 999

so this should give me the very last milisecond of this day.
But when i use this method like:

```
Date date = getLastDateOfDay();
```

Then the date has the value of: 11.07.2015 23:59:59:999

Am i missing something? Did i make something wrong?
Please help me with this.

Thx in advance.

Comment: How *exactly* are you seeing "11.07.2015 23:59:59:999"? That's not the result of `Date.toString()`, for example. Also note that currently you're using the system time zone - are you sure that's what you want?

Comment: When I do this I get the current date and 23:59:59 (in my local timezone) - we need to know how you're calling it.

Comment: `Calendar` is a bit hard to use. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31219411/does-the-setmonth-method-of-java-calendar-work-wrong, and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6722542/java-calendar-date-is-unpredictable-after-setting-day-of-week.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use Hour with 23

[see Javadoc from Calendar](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#HOUR)

> public static final int HOUR
>
> Field number for get and set indicating the hour of the morning or afternoon. HOUR is used for the 12-hour clock (0 - 11). Noon and midnight are represented by 0, not by 12. E.g., at 10:04:15.250 PM the HOUR is 10.

Comment: Thank you very much for pointing this out. Marked this answer as correct cause it was the most precise one with good explanation.

Answer (score 1):

set

```
cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 23);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try set explicit timezone for your Calendar instance, i.e:

```
final Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC");
```

This answer also can help:
[What is the default timezone for java.util.Calendar.?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20471185/what-is-the-default-timezone-for-java-util-calendar/20471441#20471441)